# Sharepoint 2007 display quick launch on web part page

Tags: quick-launch

When adding a web part page, it doesn't display the Quick Launch menu.

Does anyone know how to resolve this without accessing the Sharepoint Designer? I do not have access to it.

Comment: Doesn't display where? Menu disappears after you add the webprt?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the Web Part page you have chosen as some of them hide the menu themselves.